# Array sempre recebendo o mesmo valor [Loop em duas matrizes simultaneamente]

Tags: python, loop, for, opencv

Meu programa percorre uma imagem e atribui os valores de cor *R,G,B* a variáveis que foram comparadas com matrizes contendo as cores *R,G,B* de asfalto e terra chamadas `auxAsfalto` e `auxTerra`. A questão é: quando eu percorro a imagem na posição `i, j`, que são os pixels da horizontal e vertical, ocorre tudo normal, mas quando eu vou percorrer as matrizes que possui os valores de cor de asfalto e de terra ocorre dois erros: **1º** o *for* que percorre a matriz de cor de asfalto não sai da posição 0. Já o **2º** o for que percorre a matriz de cor de terra retorna sempre o a primeira linha da matriz. Ou seja, as estruturas de repetição não estão funcionando. Desde já agradeço.

Segue o trecho de código:

```
for i in range(img.shape[1]): #percorre a linha
    for j in range(img.shape[0]): #percorre a coluna
        auxCor = img[i,j]
        for k in range(len(corAsfalto)): #percorre a matriz corAsfalto
            auxAsfalto = corAsfalto[k]
            print("TESTE auxAsfalto: {}".format(auxAsfalto))
            if np.all(auxAsfalto) == np.all(auxCor): #verifica se as cores são iguais
                print("Cor de Asfalto em auxAsfalto: {}".format(auxCor))
                contAsfalto +=1
                break
            else:
                print("Não possui asfalto")
                break
        for l in range(len(corTerra)): #percorre a matriz corTerra
            auxTerra = corTerra[l]
            print("TeSTe auxTerra: {}".format(auxTerra))
            if np.all(auxTerra) == np.all(auxCor): #verifica se as cores são iguais
                print("Cor terra em auxCor: {}, cor Terra em auxTerra: {}".format(auxCor, auxTerra))
                contTerra += 1
                break
            else:
                break

    print("Quantidade de pixels de asfalto: %d"%contAsfalto)
    print("Quantidade de pixels de terra: %d"%contTerra)
    print("Quantidade de pixels da imagem: %d"%qntPixels)
```

Retorno:

```
Cor terra em auxCor: [132 136 117], cor Terra em auxTerra: [128.  105.1  98.9]
TESTE auxAsfalto: [154.  172.1 173.9]
Cor de Asfalto em auxAsfalto: [141 147 128]
TeSTe auxTerra: [128.  105.1  98.9]
Cor terra em auxCor: [141 147 128], cor Terra em auxTerra: [128.  105.1  98.9]
TESTE auxAsfalto: [154.  172.1 173.9]
Cor de Asfalto em auxAsfalto: [153 159 140]
TeSTe auxTerra: [128.  105.1  98.9]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo que entendi suas "matrizes" são matrizes comuns de imagens que tem o formato `(n, n, 3)` correto? e voce quer comparar as ocorrencias dos canais RGB dentro das mesmas, certo? Como vc não criou um [exemplo completo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), para entender o contexto, criei um, veja se é o que vc quer:

[TL;DR](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/use-zip-and-numpy?language=python3)

```
import numpy as np

# Criação das imagens:
img_terra = np.random.randint(222, size=(10, 10,3)) 
img_asfalto = np.random.randint(222, size=(10, 10,3))

# Forçando uma igualdade
img_terra[5] = img_asfalto[5]

# Comparando as ocorrencias nas imagens:
for im1, im2 in zip(img_asfalto, img_terra):
    if np.array_equal(im1,im2):
        ln = '*'*18
        print(ln,'Ocorrencias iguais',ln, sep='\n')
    else:
        print('ocorrencias diferentes:')
        '''
        #(1) Aqui voce pode usar um outro for com zip para 
        tratar cada elemento nas duas ocorencias:
        '''    
else:
    print("Melhor do que 'for' aninhados. :-)")
```

No meio do codigo onde anotei com `#(1)` voce poderia fazer o tratamento que desejar/precisar com cada elemento das duas imagens quando as ocorrencias forem diferentes, por exemplo, algo como:

```
for e1, e2 in zip(im1,im2):
    # Process
    # ... 
    pass
```

Veja funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/use-zip-and-numpy?language=python3)

> Editada (conforme comentário)
>   Exemplo com o zip

```
lst1  = [1, 2, 3]
lst2  = ['A', 2, 'B']
zipped = list(zip(lst1,lst2))  
print(zipped)
```

A saida é uma lista de tuplas com os pares de elementos das duas listas:

```
[(1, 'A'), (2, 2), (3, 'B')] # Lista de tuplas
```

Comparando os elementos das duas listas:

```
for e1, e2 in zip(lst1, lst2):
    if e1==e2:
        idx = lst1.index(e1)
        print('elemento:',idx, 'de lst1 é igual ao elemento', idx, 'de lst2')
```

Saida:

```
elemento 1 de lst1 é igual ao elemento 1 de lst2
```

Comment: Eu sou iniciante em python, e pelo que entendi o zip pega cada posição que for igual das duas matrizes e cria uma outra matriz com os elementos da posição de de cada array, certo? Então nesse caso toda aquele trecho de código que eu fiz pode ser resumido a isto?

Comment: Na verdade o zip cria um iterator que agrega as duas matrizes, é como se uma função para unir as duas matrizes, estou editando a resposta e adicionando  um exemplo com o `zip`.

Comment: Entendi, isso me ajudou bastante. Muito obrigado!! :)

Comment: Considere dar o aceite e um upvote (se não foi vc que o fez) na resposta. :-)